# Assign certain values to a column in data.table based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have a `data.table` (`dataframe)`. Can I create a new column with certain values based on another columns (based on the column like the picture below)?

For example, can I create a new column named `A`, with values = `c (1.2,5.6,10.3,20.4)`, and make it be corresponding to `S4,S9,S5,S10` in column `stimulus`?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier option is to convert to `factor` with `levels` specified as `unique` elements of the column and coerce to integer with `as.integer`

```
df1$A <- as.integer(factor(df1$stimulus, levels = unique(df1$stimulus)))
```

Or use `match` on the `unique` values

```
df1$A <- with(df1, match(stimulus, unique(stimulus)))
```

-Update

If it needs to be custom values, an option is also to specify the `labels` along with `levels`

```
df1$A <- with(df, as.numeric(as.character(factor(stimulus,
       levels = c("S4", "S9", "S5", "S10"), c("1.1", "2.2", "3.2" , "5.8")))))
```

---

Or a better option may to do a join/merge with a key/value dataset

```
keydat <- data.frame(stimulus = c("S4", "S9", "S5", "S10"),
            A = c(1.1, 2.2, 3.2, 5.8))
df2 <- merge(df1, keydat, all.x = TRUE)
```

Comment: hi, thank you for the solutions. Would I be able to assign specific values like `c (1.1,2.2,3.2,5.8)` and make them correspond to elements in column `stimulus`?

Comment: @Shepard I updated the solution.  Please check if that works. thanks